# Join two subquery in hql

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql-server-2008, nhibernate

How can I write this sql query in as hql:

```
select count(distinct s.id) as prepaid, count(distinct ss.id) as postpaid
from (select * from subscriber where subscriber.ispostpaid=0) s 
join (select * from subscriber where ispostpaid=1) ss 
where s.subscriber_status='active';
```

Or can make this query without using join by using only subquery.

Comment: Why have you tagged with both `[mysql]` and `[sql-server]`?

Comment: You are also missing the `ON` part in the join.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand what you're looking to return, and assuming `subscriber.id` is unique in the table (seems likely), here is a SQL Server answer (though it should be adaptable to MySQL):

```
select
    isnull(sum((case when s.ispostpaid = 0 and s.subscriber_status = 'active' then 1 else 0 end)), 0) as prepaid,
    isnull(sum((case when s.ispostpaid = 1 then 1 else 0 end)), 0) as postpaid
    from subscriber s;
```

This selectively counts the rows of interest with one table access instead of an expensive cross join and grouping in the original query. The use of `ISNULL` is to still return counts of 0 if the table is empty.

Using NHibernate, I believe this could also be written using `ICriteria`... but it's been a while for me on that. Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3591916/164901), as it might help if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
SELECT     CASE WHEN ispostpaid=0 AND subscriber_status='active' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT S.ID) END AS PrePaid,
           CASE WHEN ispostpaid=1 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT S.ID) END AS PostPaid
FROM       Subscriber
GROUP BY   ispostpaid
```

Comment: The `CASE` expressions should be inside the `COUNT()` functions.

Comment: @ypercube why it should be inside `count` function..

Comment: You can try it out. You can't reference `ispostpaid` (outside of an aggregate) when that column is not in the `GROUP BY` list.

Comment: i have executed it, its working fine in `SQL SERVER`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see the `GROUP BY ispostpaid`, did you have it when you first posted the answer? Yes, it should work with that GROUP BY, but the OP does not have such a group by in his question.

Comment: So if the op's query returned the 2 numbers, say `(3,7)` (in one row), your query would return `(3,NULL), (NULL,7)` (in two rows.) Slightly different format. And you don't take into account the `s.subscriber_status='active'` condition.

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't saw the `subscriber_status` condition. I have edited it, now it will work..